# Audio IC TDA7292 Mute pin (pin 5)

Tags: amplifier, audio

How does the mute pin work in TDA7292? I looked at the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7292.pdf), and it says that we need -6V (or below) on pin 5 to set the amplifiers active. I want the amplifiers to always active. So I'm thinking maybe we need to connect it to the -Vcc.

[image: TDA7292 Database]

But then I found this circuit in the description from a YouTube video:

[image: TDA7292 Circuit]
Image source: [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FruR280S8gS1G2RXWpoEssbOWh9fbD1G/view) in the description of YouTube video - [DIY 80w Power Amplifier Circuit | Clear Sound Using TDA7292 IC by Tech Saw](https://youtu.be/9D9cYKaOOSI)

In the circuit above, pin 5 is not connected to anything. But the amplifiers are active (based on the video). Does not connecting pin 5 to anything can make it active?

Comment: It's possible it works floating but it's an extremely bad idea to ignore the description in the datasheet in favor of a random circuit diagram that may not even work. Also the unmute voltage is not -6V, but 6V below V+, which is actually a positive voltage, so you can tie it to ground if you want to disable mute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says that we need -6V (or below) on pin 5 to set the amplifiers active

No, it says +Vs-6V which means 6 volts below the supply voltage.

[image]

They use a current source (Q1) and a bunch of resistors to generate appropriate voltages.

[This schematic](https://electro-dan.co.uk/electronics/TDA7292_TDA7265.aspx) simply uses a resistor divider and a cap to add delay. This way, both supplies have time to come up before the amplifier comes out of standby:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The voltage is down from the plus supply.  In the data sheet, see below, they made a constant current source with a transistor.  In this case the Base could be held at +5V and the emitter resistors will have 4.3V across them.  The emitter current is also going through the 15K resistors at the top of the schematic.

[image: From data sheet]

Comment: If the Base and Emitters are at the same voltage the current is zero and pin-5 is at +VS.  If only the 47k is seeing current then the current is low and pin-5 is pulled down a little.  If you are using 15k in parallel with 47K the current is high and pin-5 is pulled down more.  (assuming the base has voltage on it)